# Find a family of open sets whose intersection is compact.

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-writing

Does such intersection exists? im thinking about $An=(3+1/n;4+1/n)$  since $\bigcap An = [3,4] $ so its closed and bounded then its compact. Can someone please say whether its correct or not?

Comment: It is (if you use $3-1/n$ in the lower bound instead of $3+1/n$). But you can even find a more minimal example (exploiting the same idea).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Entirely correct. And that's because the site does not accept a comment as short as the simple "correct" :-)

Comment: you should be able to show each set is contained in the other

Comment: You probably mean $(3-\frac{1}{n}; 4+\frac{1}{n})$, and if so, you are correct. You could also go with $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$, whose intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes,sorry. i meant that. Thanks:)

Comment: Well, actually, $­­­­­∅$ is compact as well, …

Answer (score 1):

Since (as you said in the comments) you meant to have $A_n = (3 - 1/n, 4 + 1/n)$, this is correct.

---

As an interesting remark, note that *any* compact set can be obtained in this manner. If we let $E$ be a compact set and

$$E_n = \left\{x : d(x, E) < \frac 1 n\right\}$$

where $d(x, E)$ is the distance between $x$ and $E$, then $\bigcap_n E_n = E$. The sets $E_n$ are called *neighborhoods* of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Try $A_n=(-{1 \over n} , {1 \over n} )$.

Comment: Or even $∅$, right?

Comment: @k.stm: Yes, even simpler.